# Grammatical analysis of the construction "Se l'è mangiato il cane"

Tags: grammar

"My/The dog ate it" is a common joke response in English for what a student can give as an excuse when he didn't do his homework. I found the following phrase while looking for the equivalent in Italian:

> Se l'è mangiato il cane.

I would of thought a more direct translation would be:

> l'ha mangiato il cane.

Can anyone clarify what is going on grammatically and provide other examples of similar constructions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of your Italian sentences are correct: the first one makes use of a so-called “intensive” use of the verb.

First of all, assume the sentences are in the present tense. In this case we would have, for the two Italian sentences, *Se lo mangia il cane* and *Lo mangia il cane*. Here the only difference is that we have in the first case an additional personal pronoun to give some emphasis and to convey a sense of involvement in the action. It is a common construction, especially in the spoken language: *Mi bevo una birra* and *Bevo una birra* (“I drink a beer”), *Ci vediamo un bel film* and *Vediamo un bel film* (“We watch a great movie”). In these utterances, the first construction conveys a sense that we really enjoy the experience, so to say.

Beware, this are *not* reflexive verbs: *mi vedo allo specchio* (“I see myself in a mirror”) is a reflexive construction; *mi vedo “Guerre stellari”* (“I watch *Star Wars*”) isn't.

And, apart for the pronoun, there is another grammatical difference. All these examples involve transitive verbs which, usually, use the verb *avere* as their auxiliary:

- *Bevo una birra*  ->  *Ho bevuto una birra*
- *Vediamo un film*  ->  *Abbiamo visto un film*

The “intensive” construction, on the contrary, requires *essere* as its auxiliary:

- *Mi bevo una birra*  ->  *Mi sono bevuto una birra*
- *Ci vediamo un film*  ->  *Ci siamo visti un film*

(Notice *visti* rather than *visto*, agreeing with the subject, as is usual when the auxiliary verb is *essere*).

So we have arrived to your example. The pronoun *l[o]* is just a normal object (referring to *il compito*, the homework, in this case). So we may have either *L'ha mangiato il cane* (corresponding to *Vediamo un film*) or *Se l'è mangiato il cane* (corresponding to *Ci siamo visti un film*).

Some further fine points:

- The subject (*il cane*) is at the end for emphasis; *Il cane se l'è mangiato* would emphasise *mangiato*, as in, he didn't rip it or hide it, but actually eat it;
- Here *mangiato* doesn't agree with *il cane* (or it does, but by chance) but with the implicit *il compito*. This is normal when the participle follows an object expressed by a pronoun and isn't a consequence of the intensive verb: *ho mangiato la bistecca* but *l'ho mangiata*.

You can find some more information (in Italian) about this kind of construction [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-pronominali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) and [here](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_084.html).